# Can't create CloudFront distribution with standard logging despite I'm the bucket owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a CloudFront distribution for a S3 website endpoint, using AWS Console (I've also tried Terraform but the output is the same).

I want to use standard logging, and for that I created a S3 bucket with **Block all public access** enabled. I'm the owner of said bucket.

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#AccessLogsBucketAndFileOwnership), I've also added ACL permissions for *awslogsdelivery* account. However, when I try to create the distribution, I receive the following error:

> You do not have permission to use
> `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` for
> standard logging. To use this bucket, the bucket's owner will need to
> create a FULL_CONTROL access control list (ACL) for your account. Once
> you have access, please try creating the distribution again. More
> information on ACLs can be found here .

The Object Ownership is set to Bucket owner preferred.

As I said, I'm the owner of the bucket so I don't really know what's going on here. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is hard to say, when you do not provide any code. Could you include CloudFormation Template? Are you passing `LoggingConfiguration` inside it?

Comment: My second guess would be - do you own "my-bucket", or do you try to create it? Bucket names must be unique in all AWS Accounts. If you try to use it, and it is already created by some1 else - you won't have access to it. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @DawidGacek! It turns out that I was creating the bucket in eu-south-2 and apparently that doesn't work. I created it again in eu-west-2 and it worked as expected.